# io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply issue

Tags: java, flutter, dart

I am receiving error regarding Dart Messenger. Did anybody had some similar issue?

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException Reply already
> submitted io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply
> (DartMessenger.java:35)
> io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.success
> (MethodChannel.java:14)
> io.flutter.plugins.localauth.LocalAuthPlugin$1.onFailure
> (LocalAuthPlugin.java:18)
> io.flutter.plugins.localauth.AuthenticationHelper.onAuthenticationError
> (AuthenticationHelper.java:30)

```
Flutter doctor:
Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.22.6 at /Users/radmilabiga/Install/flutter
    • Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (2 months ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 2f0af37152
    • Dart version 2.10.5

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/radmilabiga/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1
 
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 50.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your flutter channel to master or beta.

```
flutter channel beta
```

OR

```
flutter channel master
```

and then clean your project and install your packages.

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```